# HTML Attribute rel Errors using fancyBox

Tags: jquery, html, fancybox

I'm using fancyBox to create a gallery with the following code:

```
<a class="fancybox" rel="group1" href="img/work/1.jpg"></a>
<a class="fancybox" rel="group1" href="img/work/2.jpg"></a>
<a class="fancybox" rel="group1" href="img/work/3.jpg"><img src="img/th/thumb.jpg" alt="Thumb" /></a>
```

But I'm getting errors while validating the code. It says:

```
Bad value group1 for attribute rel on element a: Keyword group1 is not registered.
```

How do I fix this issue? Am I not writing the code out correctly? I basically wanted one thumbnail, with 3 photos to scroll through.

Thank you.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

If you want to have a fancybox gallery within a valid `HTML` document (just because we are all purists ;) then you need two things:

1: An HTML5 DOCTYPE

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

2: use the `data-fancybox-group` attribute rather than the `rel` attribute like:

```
<a class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="group1" href="img/work/1.jpg"></a>
```

That validates!! ... see [sample here](http://picssel.com/playground/jquery/dataFancyboxGroup_28jan12.html)

**NOTE**: this is for fancybox v2.x

Answer (score 5):

> How do I fix this issue?

You rewrite the code so it doesn't try to describe the relationship between the current page and the image with the nonsense term "group1".

HTML 5 provides the `data-*` series of attributes for adding data solely for the purpose of JS. There is no need to hijack `rel`, which has a defined meaning.

Comment: Wouldn't that mean rewriting that jQuery plugin? Yes, clean solution but somewhat impractical. (I don't know the plugin, but yeah. If they're any good they already support `data-*` attributes.)

Comment: I wouldn't rewrite the plugin. Leave it alone. If it works in your browser, then fine. Validation is great to a point. You shouldn't break the rules if you don't know what you're doing, but once you know the rules, feel free to bend them (as long as your page works) is my opinion!

Comment: +1 because you mentioned _HTML5 provides the data-*_ and fancybox v2.x includes that option (see my answer below)

Answer (score 4):

If you are still using fancybox v 1.x (which does not support data-fancybox-group) you can easily modify the script a bit.

You only have to search and replace the "rel" attribute with something else, for instance "data-fancybox-gallery".

When searching for the string "rel" you will find 4 elements. Be carefull only to change the last 3, because the first "rel" you find is part of *position:**rel**ative*.

This is the part you have to change:

```
        var c = a(this).attr("rel") || "";
        if (!c || c == "" || c === "nofollow") {
            n.push(this)
        } else {
            n = a("a[rel=" + c + "], area[rel=" + c + "]");
            l = n.index(this)
        }
```

Make it:

```
        var c = a(this).attr("data-fancybox-gallery") || "";
        if (!c || c == "" || c === "nofollow") {
            n.push(this)
        } else {
            n = a("a[data-fancybox-gallery=" + c + "], area[data-fancybox-gallery=" + c + "]");
            l = n.index(this)
        }
```

And then your code should be:

```
    <a class="fancybox" data-fancybox-gallery="group1" href="img/work/1.jpg"></a>
    <a class="fancybox" data-fancybox-gallery="group1" href="img/work/2.jpg"></a>
    <a class="fancybox" data-fancybox-gallery="group1" href="img/work/3.jpg"><img src="img/th/thumb.jpg" alt="Thumb" /></a>
```

Answer (score 3):

You are getting the validation error because the rel attribute has a list of values that it is expecting (see http://www.w3schools.com/html5/att_a_rel.asp).

There is nothing you can do to fix this,  Fancybox is using the attribute for a purpose for which is was not intended.  There's nothing wrong with that.  Web pages don't have to be 100% 'valid'.

Comment: You can do something about it - see the accepted answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9037826/221381

Answer (score 1):

> How do I fix this issue?

You don't need to. The range of values that the validator accepts for the `rel` attribute is limited.

Obviously Fancybox makes use of that attribute in a way that the validator does not appreciate, so it issues <strike>a warning</strike> an error; but this does not have to concern you.

> Am I not writing the code out correctly?

Yes, you are.

Comment: @Quentin: Oh, I see. You could argue that it's okay to ignore it without risking the lives of innocent kitties. ;) But I understand it's not valid HTML and there are better ways to solve that particular problem (but the plugin authors might not have thought about those ways).

Comment: Is this an error you're getting and fancybox is not working? Or is this just a validation program giving you the errors?

Comment: @Jeremy I suspect it's the latter.

Comment: @JeremyMiller fancyBox is working fine. I just wanted to keep my code validated. Great discussion all. Thank you so much. /cc Tomalak

Comment: Yeah, I definitely think it's very good thing to do, but sometimes it's unavoidable. It'll still work perfectly fine, and chances are good no one will ever know!

Answer (score 0):

The `rel` attribute specifies the relationship between the current document and the linked document. The attribute has a limited set of possible values, listed here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_link_rel.asp. Using a non-standard value will cause a validation warning which can only be corrected by changing your rel attribute to a standard value or removing it altogether.

I'm not quite sure why you have the attribute there, however there are several alternatives that will validate correctly:

- If you are trying to store information against each item and your website uses the HTML5 doctype then you can use the data-* attribute. Example usage: data-group="1". You can then access the dataset via javascript, see here: http://slides.html5rocks.com/#custom-data
- If you are trying to access the items in a css selector then you can add "group1" as a second class to the items.
- If you are trying to access the items via JavaScript and you are not using the XHTML doctype you may alternatively consider setting their name attribute to "group1", then using the getElementsByName('group1') function.