# Multiple Fancybox 2 Galleries issue with "rel"

Tags: jquery, html, fancybox, gallery, fancybox-2

I've seen some questions that address similar issues but none of the fixes seem to work for my situation. Basically I have multiple fancybox galleries on one page throughout the site, and when one clicks through one slideshow on the site, it continues from one gallery to the next. I want the galleries/fancybox instances to remain separate from one another. Basically I need the "rel" catagories to keep galleries separate and not bleed into one another. Any help is much appreciated I've tried a few things but nothing seems to work.

Here's the only additional Javascript I've included to add social media buttons:

```
$(function(){
    $(".fancybox")
        .attr('rel', 'gallery')
        .fancybox({
            beforeShow: function () {
                if (this.title) {
                    // New line
                    this.title += '<br />';

                    // Add tweet button
                    this.title += '<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-count="none" data-url="' + "http://drewalbinson.com/" + '">Tweet</a> ';

                    // Add FaceBook like button
                    this.title += '<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=' + this.href + '&amp;layout=button_count&amp;show_faces=true&amp;width=500&amp;action=like&amp;font&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;height=23" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:110px; height:23px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>';
                }
            },
            afterShow: function() {
                // Render tweet button
                twttr.widgets.load();
            },
            helpers : {
                title : {
                    type: 'inside'
                }
            }  
        });

    });
```

Here is a simplified version of my HTML:

```
<!-- Gallery 1 -->

<div class="imagebox">
<a href="g1_img1.png" class="fancybox" rel="gallery1" title="1 of 2">

<img src="g1_img1_small.png" />

</a>

<a href="g1_img2.png" class="fancybox" rel="gallery1" title="2 of 2"></a>

</div>

<!-- Gallery 2 -->

<div class="imagebox">

<a href="g2_img1.png" class="fancybox" rel="gallery2" title="1 of 2">

<img src="g2_img1_small.png" />

</a>

<a href="g2_img2.png" class="fancybox" rel="gallery2" title="2 of 2"></a>

</div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part of your code :

```
$(".fancybox")
    .attr('rel', 'gallery')
    .fancybox({
    .... etc
```

...is overriding the `rel` attributes in your html. Just remove the `.attr()` method from it like :

```
$(".fancybox")
    .fancybox({
    .... etc
```

... and you will be fine.

Comment: As an aside, I have fancybox 2.1.5 and instead of using "rel" it now checks the "data-fancybox-group" attribute. It took me stepping through their actual code to find this.

You can override the name of the attribute to be used with the (currently undocumented) groupAttr option. For example, to change it back to rel you'd have `{groupAttr: "rel"}`

https://github.com/fancyapps/fancyBox/issues/288

Comment: @GregoryMagarshak : Fancybox 2.x actually checks either `rel` or `data-fancybox-group`. For validation purposes, it's better to use the second though. I answer to that about 2 years ago ;) http://stackoverflow.com/a/9037826/1055987