# fancyBox 'rel' for two galleries in the same page

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, fancybox

I'm using the fancyBox plugin (http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/)

I have two galleries that a locate in the same page,

I want to separate those two galleries so when the lightboxes are open it wont jump from one gallery to the next when it end showing the pictures of each gallery.

I use  the 'rel' and give rel="gallery1" and rel="gallery2"

but it still jumping from gallery to gallery,

anything I'm missing here?

Comment: Some code will be helpful

Comment: I tried out some of the examples @[fancybox](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/) and it works just fine... So you're definitely missing something.

Comment: Most likely you are using the code as explained here http://stackoverflow.com/a/17034211/1055987