# How can I group images from two different divs using Fancybox?

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I'm trying to implement [Fancybox](http://fancybox.net/howto) to a small gallery.

The gallery has one main image with thumbnails below. (See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rCBHL/1/)

I've tried to group the images by using `rel="gallery"` and `data-fancybox-group="gallery"`. But I'm still not able to see the next image by clicking the arrow (which is not showing).

Can someone spot why I'm not able to brows the images using Fancybox?

HTML Code:

```
<div class="column5 main-image">
          <div class="big">
            <a href="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2591/4135665747_3091966c91.jpg" data-fancybox-group="gallery" rel="gallery" id="large-image">
            <img alt="Prosjektbilde" src="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2591/4135665747_3091966c91.jpg">            </a>
            <div class="expand"></div>
          </div>

          <div class="project-thumbs">

                <div class="thumb">
                  <a data-fancybox-group="gallery" href="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2641/4163443812_df0b200930.jpg" rel="gallery" class="thumb_link">
                    <img src="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2641/4163443812_df0b200930_m.jpg">
                  </a>
                  <div class="mask">
                    <div class="more"></div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="thumb">
                  <a data-fancybox-group="gallery" href="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2641/4163443812_df0b200930.jpg" rel="gallery" class="thumb_link">
                    <img src="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2641/4163443812_df0b200930_m.jpg">
                  </a>
                  <div class="mask">
                    <div class="more"></div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="thumb">
                  <a data-fancybox-group="gallery" href="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2641/4163443812_df0b200930.jpg" rel="gallery" class="thumb_link">
                    <img src="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2641/4163443812_df0b200930_m.jpg">
                  </a>
                  <div class="mask">
                    <div class="more"></div>
                  </div>
                </div>          </div>
        </div>
```

Jquery code:

```
$("#large-image").attr('rel', 'gallery').fancybox({
    closeClick : true,
    padding: 0,
    helpers : {
        overlay : {
            css : {
                'background' : 'rgba(238,238,238,0.85)'
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create separate Fancybox galleries on the same page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9486034/how-to-create-separate-fancybox-galleries-on-the-same-page)

Comment: Also check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/17034211/1055987

Comment: No it's only one gallery and I found the solution.

Answer (score 0):

What I had to do, was to create a wrapper around main image and thumbnails.
Then I had to make sure all my `<a>` had `data-fancybox-group="gallery"`.

In my jQuery I had to use

```
$(".wrapper a").fancybox();
```

Now Fancybox will be applied to all links inside the wrapper.

Comment: or add the same class to all links and bind such class to fancybox as in the example provided