# Bad value fancybox-button for attribute rel on element a: The string fancybox-button is not a registered keyword or absolute URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fancybox

I use [fancyBox](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/) on my website, and I am getting a lot of errors in `Validator.w3` 
How do I get rid of these errors?

```
a rel="fancybox-button" title="Pealkiri 1" class="fancybox-button" href="image/portfolio/pulm/_U9B2529.jpg"><img src="image/portfolio/pulm/_U9B2529.jpg"  alt=""></a
```

Comment: What kind of errors ?

Comment: In http://validator.w3.org/ this error: Bad value fancybox-button for attribute rel on element a: The string fancybox-button is not a registered keyword or absolute URL

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/a/9037826/1055987