# Fancybox 2 jsfiddle explanation

Tags: jquery, html, fancybox, fancybox-2

The jsfiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/vkDcG/  to show Fancybox 2 has

```
$(".fancybox")
    .attr('rel', 'gallery')
    .fancybox({
        beforeLoad: function() {
            this.title = $(this.element).attr('caption');
        }
    });
```

Could someone explain the beforeLoad function? Is this a fancybox thing, an ajax thing?  What's happening here?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer :

The `rel` attribute specifies the relationship between the current document and the linked document (which implies that the `rel` attribute is mostly used in **"linking"** elements like `<a>`, `<area>` and `<link>` tags)

---

Long answer :

Although you can actually set any value to the `rel` attribute (as in the referred jsfiddle) there is a (non-normative) list of valid values that you can find at http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/links.html#linkTypes

Depending on your `DOCTYPE`, an html validator will show as errors/warnings
any `rel` attribute with a *non-valid* value (there some differences between HTML 4.01 and HTML5 though).

On the other hand, if you use the `rel` attribute to create a fancybox gallery (as in the code in the jsfiddle), then your document won't validate.

If you want your document to be valid AND still have a fancybox gallery, then DON'T use the `rel` attribute but the special (HTML5) `data-fancybox-group` attribute ... so you could do this instead :

```
$(".fancybox")
    .attr('data-fancybox-group', 'gallery')
    .fancybox({
        beforeLoad: function () {
            this.title = $(this.element).attr('caption');
        }
});
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/9GwUu/)**

For more information check https://stackoverflow.com/a/9037826/1055987

---

**EDIT** :

The `beforeLoad` functions is a **callback** function that is executed (as its name says) **before** the fancybox content is loaded.

Yes, its a fancybox thing and you can execute any javascript code (you want/need) inside the callback.

For more about javascript callbacks, you can read [this post](http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-callback-functions-and-use-them/)