# Open Next Inline Lightbox just like a gallery on click of next button

Tags: jquery, html, fancybox-2

I am using fancyapp and would like to show 2 images as inline lightbox, but allowing multiple inline lightbox to work like gallery , so just like a gallery user can click a next arrow to open next div so for eg

```
<a class="various" href="#inline">Inline -Multiple image</a>
<a class="various" href="#inline2">Inline</a>
<a class="various" href="#inline3">Inline</a>
<div id='inline' class=''></div>
<div id='inline2' class=''></div>
<div id='inline3' class=''></div>
```

on click of anchor tag with href=#inline2 and next is clicked inline3 div gets opened and if we press left keyboard key/arrow inline1 gets opened, so basically same as gallery functionality but as inline .
Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rigids/mx61yqpd/)

Comment: you need to add a `rel` attribute (or a `data-fancybox-group` attribute) to your **anchors** (not to the `div`s in the galley) to create a gallery (regardless is an inline, images or hybrid gallery). see http://stackoverflow.com/a/9487189/1055987 or http://stackoverflow.com/a/9037826/1055987 for more

Comment: Or see your forked jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ffk87a35/

Comment: I have BEFORE AFTER IMAGE in 1 div and i need to show both and on click of next button in lightbox need to show next set within same page