# Prestashop 1.6 deletes fancybox's rel attribute from images

Tags: php, fancybox, prestashop, fancybox-2, prestashop-1.6

I have a problem with my prestashop store:

My coder (which isn't available anymore) implemented fancybox into galleries which i have in almost every cms page in the store. They all work well - fancybox has Next/Previous buttons, displays correctly.

But when i tried to create a new cms page with a new gallery and copy the code from any of already created pages, i received an error that the content is invalid, because all existing pages somehow contain

```
<script>// <![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        openEffect  : 'none',
        closeEffect : 'none'
    });
});
// ]]></script>
```

while the editor does not allow scripts. But all the existing pages have this fancybox script somehow implemented.

Following these two tutorials tutorials
`http:// tonalidad .es/blog-de-notas/galerias-en-prestashop-1-6-con-fancybox/`   and

```
http:// fancyapps .com/fancybox/#docs
```

I added the above script to my theme's `cms.tpl` file, and now new images in the new gallery appear in fancybox's frame, but they don't have a next/previous functions. I rechecked the html and noticed that the editor deletes the `rel=""` attribute from every image, which is supposed to group them.

Thus images don't group, therefore i guess next/previous doesn't appear. That's my best guess but maybe i'm wrong.

Any advice mates? Included two screens.

[existing pages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l4iYa.png) [new page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AoP4e.png)

Comment: To me it looks like the working pages with galleries are of different type (pages created by modules), which don't purify HTML before saving. Can you confirm?

Comment: Sveikas =) Thanks for your attention. I looked through all the Front Office modules, there are some, which could potentially be involved, but they didn't seem to hold any responsible configuration. At least none of them hold exact code, which is generated in the genuine editor.

Comment: The question is, where are you editing existing pages with working galleries? Are they CMS objects (pages)? If so, does every setting match (maybe there's and option in edit form that tell to save the gallery code properly. I'd check the database table where gallery pages are save for extra column. Second, I'd check overrides and modules hooks which interact with the working gallery objects.

Comment: I don't know prestashop but if you suspect the `rel` attribute is being deleted then try the `data-fancybox-group` instead. Check http://stackoverflow.com/a/9037826/1055987 for more

Comment: Tried that, deletes it as well...