# How to change REL attribute to other

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, rel

I have a problem with W3 validator. Here is the code:

```
<div class="flexslider content-slider">
  <ul class="slides">
    <li>
      <div class="inner">
        <a **href="pic/slider-img1.jpg" class="fancy-gallery" rel="gallery"**>
          <img src="pic/slider-litt-img1.jpg" alt="gallery-pic">
        </a>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

What i have to do to replace rel with id attribute? Im newbie... Should i need to rewrite js code also?
Here is the js code:

```
if($('.fancy-gallery')[0]) {
        $('.fancy-gallery').fancybox({padding:10});
    }
```

Comment: Why the heck does someones still bother about W3 validator in 2015 ?

Comment: why i shouldn't do that?

Comment: isn't it more effective for SEO?

Comment: Um, changing the rel attribute to id with jQuery is too late if you are worried about SEO or validation.

Comment: @PierreGayvallet — Because it's a bloody good tool for identifying stupid mistakes which cause rendering problems and subtle errors which might not be noticed by most manual testing. (It also identifies issues that browsers are generally OK at recovering from by themselves, but life is generally simpler if you write real HTML in the first place).

Comment: "What i have to do to replace rel with id attribute?" — You'll probably want to use class instead of ID, but you just use a text editor as with any other HTML. "Should i need to rewrite js code also?" — Probably, but since we don't know what JS you are using, we can't tell you how.

Comment: @Quentin if you say so. Any example of "subtle" errors creating rendering issues and impacting performance ?

Comment: @Quentin this is it? $(window).load(function(){
 
 if($('.flexslider.content-slider')[0]) {
  $('.flexslider.content-slider').flexslider({
   animation: "slide",
   animationLoop: true,
   itemWidth: 159,
   itemMargin: 0,
   prevText: '',
   nextText: '',
   controlNav: false, 
   directionNav: true
  });

  $(window).on('resize', function(){
   $('.flexslider.content-slider').data("flexslider").flexAnimate(0);
  })
 };

 if($('.fancy-gallery')[0]) {
  $('.fancy-gallery').fancybox({padding:10});
 }
});

Comment: I updated the JS code, any ideas?

Comment: @Dimkin — You seem to be using various different libraries. You'll have to look at their documentation and/or source code to figure out which ones are misusing the rel attribute and if they have built-in alternatives or need editing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML Attribute rel Errors using fancyBox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9037061/html-attribute-rel-errors-using-fancybox)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is more simplier.. I had to change **rel** to '**data-fancybox-group**'. And w3 like it, more over script works.